# Using Ruby to scan through a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to create a regex to gather info from strings that look like this:

```
A22xB67-E34...
```

for any number.

I have the regex:

```
@spaceCode = "[A-Z]([A-Z0-9][0-9]|[0-9])"
@moveCode=/^(?<one>#{@spaceCode})((?<mode>x|\-)(?<two>#{@spaceCode}))+$/
```

However I get:

```
s="A11-A22xA33".scan(@moveCode)
=> [["A11", "11", "xA33", "x", "A33", "33"]]
```

which is most definatly NOT what I want.

The string could be any length of C22 etc, with either `x` or `-` as the seperator, and put it into an array like:

```
['A22','x',B22','-'.......]
```

Examples:

```
"A22xB23-D23xE25" => ['A22','x','B23','=','D23','E25;]
"AA2xA9-A1" => ['AA2','x','A9','-','A1']
```

Comment: Trying this in IRB, I got: "RegexpError: undefined (?...) sequence: /^(?<one>[A-Z]([A-Z0-9][0-9]|[0-9]))((?<mode>x|\-)(?<two>[A-Z]([A-Z0-9][0-9]|[0-9])))+$/"

Comment: @JohnDibling It works fine through irb on rails with me :S

Comment: @MartinVidner I was hoping I could get an array of something like `['A11',['-','A22','x','A33']]`

Comment: I have to admit that I don't really know what "irb on rails" means. :(

Comment: that is expected since u r using `named groups` which itself contains a `group`

Comment: `rails console` in a Rails project ... it's irb in the context of your Rails app.

Comment: `"A22xB23-D23xE25" => ['A22','x','B23','=','D23','E25;]` doesn't make sense. Where does `=` come from in the parsed array? And what happened to the second `x` in the parsed array? And where did the `;` come from in `E25;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
MOVE_REGEX = /[a-z]+\d+/i
REGEX = /(#{ MOVE_REGEX })([x-]?)/i

class String
  def parse_move
    self.scan(REGEX).flatten.reject(&:empty?)
  end
end

"A22xB23-D23xE25".parse_move
# => ["A22", "x", "B23", "-", "D23", "x", "E25"]

"AA2xA9-A1".parse_move
# => ["AA2", "x", "A9", "-", "A1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to find these three alphanumeric codes in isolation?
Would this simpler regex (or a variant on it) do what you want?

```
def decode string
  puts "\nDecoding #{string}"
  code = "[A-Z0-9]{1,3}"
  sep = "[-x=]"
  r = /(?:(#{code})#{sep}?)?/
  string.scan(r)
end

puts decode("A22xA33")
puts decode("A11-A22xA33")
puts decode("A22xB67-E34")
puts decode("A22xC33xD44-E55")
puts decode("A22xB23-D23=E25")
```

or if you want to capture actions/separators too, something like:

```
r = /(?:#{code}#{sep}?)?/
```

or to capture actions/separators in the array as separate items between the codes:

```
r = /(#{code})?(#{sep})?/
```

So I think what you want is:

```
def decode string
  puts "\nDecoding #{string}"
  code = "[A-Z0-9]{1,3}"
  sep = "[-x=]"
  r = /(#{code})?(#{sep})?/
  string.scan(r)
end
```

or in its simplest form just:

```
string.scan(/([A-Z0-9]{1,3})?([-x=])?/)
```

Comment: Afraid not. basically this is for a variable sequence of moves, that can either be move, or captre, so it could look like `AA2xA33` or `AA2-A33xB44` or even `A22xC33xD44-E55`

Comment: Edited reply to deal with variable length patterns. I think this matches your examples. You should put a list of examples to match in your question to make it clearer.

Comment: let me do that, sorry for the trouble caused here, and thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Use method like `split` with the regex as `([x-])`

---

Your `regex` won't work for your input since this would always overwrite the groups `spaceCode` and `mode`, i.e. `spaceCode` and `mode` would contain only the last matched `spaceCode` and `mode`.

For example, the regex `^(\d)+$` for input `3664` would capture only `4` not `3`,`6`,`6`,`4` in the group.

Comment: That gets it closer, but still only captures the first and last of the regex

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should work, given that field names can be variable length:

```
def parse_moves(s)    
  s.scan(/([A-Z0-9]+)?([-x])?/).flatten.compact
end
```

Results for your examples:

```
1.9.3-p125 :027 > moves = ["A11-A22xA33", "A22xB23-D23xE25", "AA2xA9-A1"]
 => ["A11-A22xA33", "A22xB23-D23xE25", "AA2xA9-A1"] 
1.9.3-p125 :028 > moves.each { |s| puts parse_moves(s).to_s }
["A11", "-", "A22", "x", "A33"]
["A22", "x", "B23", "-", "D23", "x", "E25"]
["AA2", "x", "A9", "-", "A1"]
```